# stock chart on mobile, hard to hover the last series point with finger

Tags: mobile, hover, highcharts

To see the problem, try accessing the last data point on the multi-series stock demo with a mobile device.  My hit rate is less than 50% on the last point on a series (finger hovering)

I tried setting margin-right and spacing-right but no help.  The problem is that the last data point is on the edge of the plotting area so it is harder to access with finger.  Is it possible to add some padding on the x-axis so that it is easier to hover the last data point?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set maxPadding paramter?

Comment: Thank you so much.  max/min Padding does the trick!

Comment: I added it as answer (you can mark it also), then it will be more transparent for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use minPadding / maxPadding parameters http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding / http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding